# Send SSH Command PHP

Tags: php, ssh

Hey everyone I need a function that is super simple and sends SSH commands from my Web Server with SSH2 extension installed

This is what I use now but SSH2 sucks and is impossible to install

```
<?php
$method = $_GET['method'];
$command = $_GET['command'];
$serverusername = $_GET['serverusername'];
$serverip = $_GET['serverip'];
$serverpassword = $_GET['serverpassword'];
$serverport = $_GET['serverport'];

if(!($con = ssh2_connect($serverip, $serverport))) die("Failed connecting to backend server.");
if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, $serverusername, $serverpassword)) die("Failed connecting to backend server.");
ssh2_exec($con, $command);

echo "Command sent";
?>
```

Can I get something similar to that that accepts all these variables

```
$method = $_GET['method'];
$command = $_GET['command'];
$serverusername = $_GET['serverusername'];
$serverip = $_GET['serverip'];
$serverpassword = $_GET['serverpassword'];
$serverport = $_GET['serverport'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use 
[This library](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)

use it like:

```
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

Comment: Well I am running WampServer on a Windows system, would that still work?

Comment: Why not!! if u are ssh(ing) on a linux machine it would work!

Comment: Can you help me or no? It's not a linux machine... I have been told you can do this through fsock

Comment: Wait..Ypu are ona a WAMP machine. Ypu want to ssh a Linux machine?? OR  you are on wamp and want to ssh wamp machine?

Comment: The library sankalp mentioned should work on ANY PHP install, be it on Linux, Windows, Mac, Mac OS 9, whatever. Uses fsockopen, as you noted it'd have to, and PHP code to format everything appropriately. Try it out.

Comment: Just unzip it into a folder and update the include_path as appropriate. http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net includes an example of how the include_path can be updated.